# How to hide 0's when there is no data to calculate without using custom number formats

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2019

Below is part of a financial worksheet to calculate profit and loss.

Currently `C19` shows `£ 0.00` as there is no data in the next to calculate an answer.

I want cell  `C19`  to return blank until such a point there is data in the next sheet to calculate an answer but NOT using custom number formats (as I am already using one that I would like to keep)

Custom number format already in use in cell  `C19`  :  `+ £ #,##0.00;- £ #,##0.00; 0.00`

This is currently the formula in cell  `C19`  : `=SUMIF('SPREADS LOG'!A:A,"*OPEN*",'SPREADS LOG'!K:K)`

Can anyone suggest the correct formula needed?

Comment: Maybe `=IF(SUMIF('SPREADS LOG'!A:A,"*OPEN*",'SPREADS LOG'!K:K)=0,"",SUMIF('SPREADS LOG'!A:A,"*OPEN*",'SPREADS LOG'!K:K))`?

Comment: Check if there is **any** entry by using `COUNTIF` or `COUNTIFS`

Comment: @VBasic2008 perfect solution. Can the same be done with ```=TEXT(SUM('SPREADS LOG'!M:M)," £ #,##0.00")  & " / " & TEXT(SUM('SPREADS LOG'!K:K)," £ #,##0.00")``` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 4 solutions:

1. Change your cell formating to: + £ #,##0.00;- £ #,##0.00;
2. Change the formula as the previous answer, but if you have 365 you can use the new LET function to calculate the SUMIF only once:
   =LET(**mySUMIF**,IF(SUMIF('SPREADS LOG'!A:A,"*OPEN*",'SPREADS LOG'!K:K)=0,"",SUMIF('SPREADS LOG'!A:A,"*OPEN*",'SPREADS LOG'!K:K)),IF(**mySUMIF**=0,"",**mySUMIF**))
3. Use Conditional formatting to have the same color of the cell as the background.
4. Change the Excel setting to not display any 0 values:
   **File** > **Options** > **Advanced**
   Select your worksheet and then unselect the option **Show a zero in cells that have zero value**.

Comment: Hi @Florin, thanks for your answer. I used Vbasic2008's solution in his comment! Again thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the number format to TEXT formula:

```
=TEXT(SUMIF('SPREADS LOG'!A:A,"*OPEN*",'SPREADS LOG'!K:K);"+ £ #,##0.00;- £ #,##0.00; ")
```

There is a optimization problem using

> IF(SUMIF(...)=0,",SUMIF())

since you'll end calculate the sum twice.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid changing formatting my go to when hiding zeros is to rely on the fact that divide by zero will produce an error. So `=IFERROR(1/(1/value),"")` will produce blanks if value is ever zero and will otherwise produce the value. It avoids typing in a separate check for zero entries.

In the case in question it would just be:

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/SUMIF('SPREADS LOG'!A:A,"*OPEN*",'SPREADS LOG'!K:K)),"")
```